# Premature end of file exception when sending Soap XML content with a length greater than 1448 bytes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, amazon-ec2, coldfusion, savon

I am using the Savon gem when posting data from a Ruby on Rails app hosted on an Amazon EC2 server to a ColdFusion based Soap webservice also hosted on a different Amazon EC2 server. I can post to a number of the webservices successfully but when I try to send a request with a Content-Length greater than **1448 bytes** it fails with the following error:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
      <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
      <faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.</faultstring>
      <detail>
        <ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ip-xx-xx-xx-xx</ns1:hostname>
      </detail>
    </soapenv:Fault>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The weird thing is that I can successfully post the same request from my local development machine and even from one of my other Heroku servers that I tried just to test things out.

I have played with the data that I am sending and have determined that it is definitely an overall content-length issue and not related to specific elements in the XML. I know the XML is formatted properly because I can post from my other servers. It is only causing an error when sending from my production EC2 server.

Is there some setting on EC2 that might cause issues with content lengths of over **1448 bytes**?

Comment: There are a number of throttling technologies in CF. One is the limit of the size of posted data - although 1.3k doesn't sound like much, someone may have set it very low. The second one is the total number of form posts allowed (defaulted to 100 fields). Not sure if that's "picked up" by webservice requests - I kind of doubt it. But that's all that comes to mind on the CF side. I would look for URLdefender or some other intermediate sniffing technology designed to sense and delay or prevent DOS attacks.

Comment: That particular number also reminds a possible [TCP fragmentation issue](https://www.google.com/search?hl=cs&q=1448%20bytes). Perhaps there is a firewall or something, somewhere, that passes through only the first packet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the MTU setting on the sending Amazon EC2 Server. it was set to 9001 and I think that larger packets were being chopped by the receiving server which I believe is set to 1500.

Once I changed the setting on the sending server to 1500 it solved the issue.

This is the page I read that helped provide the answer:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-drop-issues.html

And this page has the actual commands I used to change the MTU setting on the sending server:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-drop-issues.html#set-mtu

**To set MTU on a Linux operating system**

If your client runs in a Linux operating system, you can review and set the MTU value by using the ip command.

Run the following command to determine the current MTU value:

```
$ ip link show eth0
```

Review the value following mtu in the output.

If the value is not 1500, run the following command to set it:

```
$ sudo ip link set dev eth0 mtu 1500
```

Knowing that the problem happened on content-lengths greater than 1448 was critical in finding the issue!